# How to display Non Zero Values in MySQL Query

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

Hi im creating a simple Inventory system for my project. the query below shows me perfectly the Total Stocks remaining for each product. now i have to control the system or the view, if the 'TOTAL STOCKS' field(column) becomes zero, i dont want it to show anymore in my  query. only those who are greater than zero value

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.tbl_locposition AS 'Position',t1.tbl_locname AS 'Location Name', 
t2.tbl_productname AS 'Product', SUM(t0.tbl_qtyin) - SUM(t0.tbl_qtyout)  AS 'Total Stocks', 
t0.tbl_datereceived AS 'Date Received', t0.tbl_datemanufactured AS 'Date Manufactured', 
t0.tbl_threadcolor AS 'Thread Color', t2.tbl_productid AS 'Product ID', t1.tbl_locid AS 'Location 
ID', t3.tbl_truckid AS 'Truck ID', t3.tbl_truckcode AS 'Truck Code' 

FROM tbl_movement t0 
INNER JOIN tbl_products t2 ON t0.`tbl_prodid` = t2.`tbl_productid` 
INNER JOIN tbl_location t1 ON t0.`tbl_locid`  = t1.`tbl_locid` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_trucks t3 ON t0.`tbl_truckid` = t3.`tbl_truckid` 

GROUP BY t0.tbl_locid, t0.tbl_prodid  ORDER BY t0.tbl_datemanufactured ASC
```

The query works perfectly but when Total Stocks become zero. i want to remove it. anyone who can help? here is the sample picture of the data.

[Query Image Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFxI8.png)

Comment: Having clause might be your solution here https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-having.aspx/

Comment: @Hursey Thanks a lot. Having Clause solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use HAVING

```
INNER JOIN tbl_location t1 ON t0.`tbl_locid`  = t1.`tbl_locid` 
LEFT JOIN tbl_trucks t3 ON t0.`tbl_truckid` = t3.`tbl_truckid`

HAVING SUM(t0.tbl_qtyin) - SUM(t0.tbl_qtyout) > 0;

GROUP BY t0.tbl_locid, t0.tbl_prodid  ORDER BY t0.tbl_datemanufactured ASC
```